# Check if pandas column contains text in another dataframe and replace values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, contains

I have two df's, one for user names and another for real names. I'd like to know how I can check if I have a real name in my first df using the data of the other, and then replace it.
For example:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'userName':['peterKing', 'john', 'joe545', 'mary']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'realName':['alice','peter', 'john', 'francis', 'joe', 'carol']})

df1
userName
0   peterKing
1   john
2   joe545
3   mary

df2
realName
0   alice
1   peter
2   john
3   francis
4   joe
5   carol
```

My code should replace 'peterKing' and 'joe545' since these names appear in my df2. I tried using pd.contains, but I can only verify if a name appears or not.
The output should be like this:

```
userName
0   peter
1   john
2   joe
3   mary
```

Can someone help me with that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `loc[row, colum]`, [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.loc.html?highlight=series%20loc#pandas.Series.loc) you can see the documentation about `loc` method. And [Series.str.contain](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html?highlight=contain) method to select the usernames you need to replace with the real names. In my opinion, this solution is clear in terms of readability.

```
for real_name in df2['realName'].to_list():
  df1.loc[ df1['userName'].str.contains(real_name), 'userName' ] = real_name
```

Output:

```
   userName
0   peter
1   john
2   joe
3   mary
```